# change the value in tooltips in plotly

Tags: plotly

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
dataset = data.frame(x = c(1,10, 100, 1000),
                 y = c(1000, 100, 10, 1))
p = ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + 
scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
ggplotly(p)
```

With above codes, you can have a plotly graph with tooltip. The x and y axis show the original data. But the values in tooltip is shown as (0,3), (1,2), (2,2), (3,0). What I want in the tooltip is (1, 1000), (10, 100), (100, 10), (1000, 1).

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly does not take the input values as numbers but instead overwrites the axis labels.

```
> gp$x$data[[1]]$x
[1] 0 1 2 3
> gp$x$data[[1]]$y
[1] 3 2 1 0
```

Changing the x and y-values would cause even more work because the tooltip shows text which is independent of those values. The easiest solution in this example would be to overwrite the `text` attribute.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
x <- c(1,10, 100, 1000)
y <- c(1000, 100, 10, 1)
dataset = data.frame(x = x,
                     y = y)
p = ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()

gp <- ggplotly(p)
gp$x$data[[1]]$text = paste(x, y, sep='<br />')
gp
```