# how to make my ggplotly tootip show the original value when axis log-transformed

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have a plotly histogram where x-axis is log tranformed. I'm trying to make my histogram tooltip show the original value rather than the log10-transformed value.  I'm referring to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698196/change-the-value-in-tooltips-in-plotly). Overwriting the text attribute.

Below is my code.  However, my tooltip does not show anything.  Does anyone know how I can modify the text attributes in this case?

```
g=iris %>% 
  #select(Petal.Length) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length))+
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_x_log10()
gg <- ggplotly(g)
gg$x$data[[1]]$text = paste(x,y)
gg
```

Answer (score 0):

Define what you want to show inside `aes()`, and then call it in `ggplotly`.

```
g=iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length, text=paste("X:",iris$Petal.Length) )) +
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_x_log10()
gg <- ggplotly(g, tooltip=c("text"))
gg
```